# Some tests failure when build systemML project

Tags: machine-learning, systemml

I cloned systemML project and follow the guide i can build the project using 'mvn clean package'. But i can't run all tests using 'mvn verify'. 
Error like this

> testCSVSingleVDenseMR(org.apache.sysml.test.integration.functions.data.FullReblockTest)  Time elapsed: 2.109 sec  <<< FAILURE!
>   java.lang.AssertionError: failed to run script ./src/test/scripts/functions/data/SingleReblockTest.dml
>   exception: org.apache.sysml.api.DMLException: org.apache.sysml.runtime.DMLRuntimeException: org.apache.sysml.runtime.DMLRuntimeException: ERROR: Runtime error in program block generated from statement block between lines 22 and 23 -- Error evaluating instruction: jobtype = CSV_REBLOCK

I already have R3.2.3 in my path, but some dependence can't be installed successfully

> Warning messages:
>   1: In install.packages(c("batch", "bitops", "boot", "caTools", "data.table",  :
>     installation of package ‘openssl’ had non-zero exit status
>   2: In install.packages(c("batch", "bitops", "boot", "caTools", "data.table",  :
>     installation of package ‘gdtools’ had non-zero exit status
>   3: In install.packages(c("batch", "bitops", "boot", "caTools", "data.table",  :
>     installation of package ‘XML’ had non-zero exit status
>   4: In install.packages(c("batch", "bitops", "boot", "caTools", "data.table",  :
>     installation of package ‘topicmodels’ had non-zero exit status
>   5: In install.packages(c("batch", "bitops", "boot", "caTools", "data.table",  :
>     installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
>   6: In install.packages(c("batch", "bitops", "boot", "caTools", "data.table",  :
>     installation of package ‘svglite’ had non-zero exit status
>   7: In install.packages(c("batch", "bitops", "boot", "caTools", "data.table",  :
>     installation of package ‘OAIHarvester’ had non-zero exit status
>   8: In install.packages(c("batch", "bitops", "boot", "caTools", "data.table",  :
>     installation of package ‘covr’ had non-zero exit status

Answer (score 0):

This is typically a file-permissions issue. I experienced a similar problem when first running SystemML on OS X.

A couple potential solutions are:

1. Set the scratch default in SystemML-config.xml to a temporary folder location. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SYSTEMML-251.
2. Set permissions of parent folders to 755.

A discussion of this issue appears on the SystemML dev email list at: https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@systemml.incubator.apache.org/msg00442.html